# Error: 767: unexpected token at '{ when install node in macOS

Tags: node.js, macos

when I am install node in macOS Catalina using this command:

```
brew install node@10.12.0
```

shows this error:

```
➜  ~ brew install node@10.12.0
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
almighty                  firmaec                   remarkable
ankama                    flacon                    remix-ide
archi                     gcs                       remotion
bespoke                   google-chat-electron      ricochet-refresh
biglybt                   immersed                  sdm
cloudash                  jupyterlab                semeru-jdk-open
coarchi                   keyman                    smplayer
dockview                  mathcha-notebook          thetimemachinemechanic
dropbox-capture           nimblenote                tidelift
epilogue-operator         notunes                   universal-gcode-platform
far2l                     plistedplus               wondershare-edrawmax
fig                       rancher
==> Updated Casks
Updated 849 casks.
==> Deleted Casks
edrawmax                                nosqlclient
google-backup-and-sync                  phocus
google-photos-backup-and-sync           qtvlm
microsoft-lync                          rcloneosx
microsoft-r-open                        tcl
Error: 767: unexpected token at '{
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "antlr2": "antlr@2",
=======
  "ansible19": "ansible@19",
  "ansible20": "ansible@20",
  "antlr2": "antlr@2",
  "antlr3": "antlr@3",
  "apache-spark15": "apache-spark@15",
  "apache-spark16": "apache-spark@16",
>>>>>>> exploitdb 2019-07-03 (#41601)
  "app-engine-java-sdk": "app-engine-java",
  "ark": "velero",
  "arm": "nyx",
  "artifactory-cli-go": "jfrog-cli-go",
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "badtouch": "authoscope",
  "bash-completion2": "bash-completion@2",
=======
  "autoconf213": "autoconf@213",
  "autoconf264": "autoconf@264",
  "automake112": "automake@112",
  "bash-completion2": "bash-completion@2",
  "bazel02": "bazel@0.2",
>>>>>>> exploitdb 2019-07-03 (#41601)
  "beanstalk": "beanstalkd",
  "berkeley-db4": "berkeley-db@4",
  "bigdata": "blazegraph",
  "bison27": "bison@2.7",
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
  "boost-python159": "boost-python@1.59",
>>>>>>> exploitdb 2019-07-03 (#41601)
  "boost155": "boost@1.55",
  "boost157": "boost@1.57",
  "boost159": "boost@1.59",
  "boost160": "boost@1.60",
  "boot2docker": "docker-machine",
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "bro": "zeek",
=======
>>>>>>> exploitdb 2019-07-03 (#41601)
  "camlistore": "perkeep",
  "cassandra21": "cassandra@2.1",
  "cassandra22": "cassandra@2.2",
  "cdiff": "ydiff",
<<<<<<< HEAD
  "cloog018": "cloog",
  "commonmark": "cmark",
  "confluent-oss": "confluent-platform",
  "cppformat": "fmt",
  "crystal-lang": "crystal",
  "curl-openssl": "curl",
  "cv": "progress",
  "cyassl": "wolfssl",
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want 10.12.0 ? Maybe try `brew install node@12`